# Ruby, Nokogiri: sort nodeset by attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I would like to sort a Nokigiri nodeset by the title value. Tried the following code, but sorting is not working :/ Any suggestions?

```
doc.xpath("//item").sort{|x,y| x.xpath('foo:attr[@name="title"]/@value').text <=> y.xpath('foot:attr[@name="title"]/@value').text }
```

XML example:

```
<item>
  <foo:attr name="title" value="a"/>
</item>
<item>
  <foot:attr name="title" value="c"/>
</item>
<item>
  <foor:attr name="title" value="b"/>
</item>
```

Output I am looking for: (nodeset)

```
<item>
  <foo:attr name="title" value="a"/>
</item>
<item>
  <foot:attr name="title" value="b"/>
</item>
<item>
  <foor:attr name="title" value="c"/>
</item>
```

Comment: I don't think it really makes sense to sort nodes like that. Maybe you can describe your goal.

Comment: It's a workaround to do some sorting on a XML feed. The API does not support sorting, so I have to do it like this. Is it possible?

Comment: can you just give more info on what o/p you are expecting..a sample o/p will be gr8

Comment: Updated question with expected output.

Comment: You have three different namespaces?

Comment: All items are contained in a Channel namespace..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your request, you want to remove them, then sort the array, then add them back:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML.parse(data)
nodes = xml.root.css("item").remove
nodes.sort_by{ |node|
  node.css("attr")[0].attr("value"))
}.each{ |node|
  xml.root.add_child(node)
}
```

Comment: Had to add .to_i to after .attr("value") - sort_by does not work if you try sort a string that contains a float.